# UIView animation skips first animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Very new to this sorry!

As soon as I run press the button "press" The background color of UIView "Background" changes instantly to blue and then animates to purple, completely skipping the animation to yellow, then to blue.

What have I done wrong?

```
  @IBAction func Press(sender: AnyObject) {

UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
self.Background.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
self.Background.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.Background.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
}, completion:{(Bool)  in
println("COLOR CHANGED")
})
}
```

Comment: By the way, this code is wrong: `(Bool)  in`. It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't do what you think it does. Just write `_ in`.

Comment: And stop using capital letters for function names and variable names! Capital letters are for class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot animate **more than one state change** to the same property in a single `UIView.animateWithDuration` call. It will just animate to the last state change(like in your case). Instead you can chain them together using the `completionBlock`.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5/3.0, animations: {

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    }, completion:{ finished1 in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5/3.0, animations: {

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            }, completion:{finished2  in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(5/3.0, animations: {

                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

                    }, completion:{finished3  in

                        println("COLOR CHANGED")
                })
        })
})
```

Or you can use keyframe animations, specifying intermediate frames like the following. The `relativeDuration` should be a value between 0 and 1, indicating the relative duration of one keyframe. for example if the whole animation is `3 seconds` and relativeDuration is `(1/3)`, then that keyframe will animate for `3/3 = 1` second.

`relativeStartTime` is similarly the relative time after which the keyframe starts with respect to the duration of the whole animation. for example if the whole animation is `3 seconds` and relativeStartTime is `(1/3)`, then that keyframe will start after `1 second`

```
var duration = 5.0;
var relativeDuration = 1.0/3;

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2 * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    })
    }, completion:nil);
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, because that is all *one* change to *one* property. You need to make this *three successive different* animations. First animate to yellow; when that ends, now make a whole new animation to blue; then make a whole new animation to purple.

The easiest way to chain them is to put each new animation in the completion handler of the previous animation. Like this (you will need to change some other things because I refuse to write code where functions and variables start with capitals):

```
@IBAction func press(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0/3.0, animations: {
        self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        }, completion:{(Bool)  in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0/3.0, animations: {
                self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0/3.0, animations: {
                        self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                        }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                            println("COLOR CHANGED")
                    })
            })
    })
}
```

On iOS 8 there's also a more elegant (but harder) way, which is to use a keyframe animation. But to get started I would advise you to do it the easy way first!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How would I get all of this code to repeat itself infinitely?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do it this way. I'd use a keyframe animation and set it to repeat indefinitely. Or even do the whole thing at the level of Core Animation; see my book on how to do that: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_core_animation